# Traditional German e sans-serif letter

Tags: fonts, math-mode, german

I am currently translating an old physics paper from German into English (Elektron und Gravitation I by Hermann Weyl in 1929) and in one of the formulas two different characters for the letter E are used. This is explained by the following description by the author (translated): "The division of a quantity with a Latinx index/character by epsilon is, as usual, denoted by transforming the Latin character into a German one. The [image: Formula]

So, in the figure the RHS of the equation is using the Latin letter for e, while the LHS uses the German letter for e.

Now my question: How can I reproduce this using LaTeX? Currently, I am just writing:

```
\[e^p(\alpha) = \frac{e^p(\alpha}{\varepsilon}\]
```

But this is clearly not what the author wants to do, so I am looking for some way to change the e letter on the LHS be a different symbol. I've tried using Detexify but couldn't find any symbol that looks similar to the e on the LHS.

Comment: For future reference: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14). Oddly enough, the `\mathfrak` capability of `amssymb` is not actually mentioned in the LaTeX Symbols Guide. (part of your TeX distribution).  But it's still usually the best place to start.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The symbol you are after is available with `\mathfrak{e}` (from the `amssymb` package, or any other package providing old german fraktur letters).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}


\[\mathfrak{e}^p(\alpha)=\frac{e^p(\alpha)}{\varepsilon}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, that looks exactly like I wanted.

Comment: @Olorun Please accept this answer by clicking on the check mark to its left. Accepting and upvoting is the way to say thank you here. You could also close two more posts of yours like this and get them off the unanswered-list. Thank you!